# Which component of Mule 4.1 replaces Mule 3.9 timer-interceptor

Tags: anypoint-studio, mule-esb, mule4

Which component of Mule 4.1 replaces Mule 3.9 `<timer-interceptor>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. Mule 3 interceptors are not supported in Mule 4. You might rbe able to replace them somewhat with custom policies, as mentioned in the migration documentationhttps://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/migration-core

The reason is that Mule 4 architecture is very different in thread management and it doesn't allow the interceptors implementation.

Comment: Any example of custom logging policy you want me to point using Mule 4.x?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of any examples. Having said that, I'll update the answer with another possible solution for some use cases.

Comment: Sure, waiting for any possible solution.